# Configure a sonar view in the dashboard to only display specific modules

Tags: sonarqube

Sonar allows to analyze a project that is composed of several modules (multi-module project).

The idea is to analyze a large project that contains several modules, where in some cases different modules are maintained by different teams.

Then it would be helpful if we could create dedicated views to assign to different teams, based on the responsibility, where we could only display specific modules of a project, or even combine/group modules of different projects.

I've explored all the options in the dashboard configuration and I couldn't find anything similar, only the option to group projects, not modules.

Is this possible? Or is there any extension that provides this?

Answer (score 1):

This will be possible with the Views plugin: http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/ when the following ticket is implemented: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/VIEWS-173

Comment: Is there any estimate of when it will be available?

Comment: Currently planned in version 2.3. See http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/VIEWS/fixforversion/10415